# How to implement aws secret manager for multiple project applications

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-secrets-manager, spring-cloud-aws

Referring this [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/server/environment-repository/aws-secrets-manager-backend.html)
I want to implement aws secret manager for multiple projects which are connected via one common-service project and I am using this reference in the common-service but unable to achieve it.

I am also referring this [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/server/environment-repository/aws-secrets-manager.html), But I guess, I missed something and there is something that is not mentioned in this document.

I want to use and access all secrets from common-service to all other projects.

Comment: It is same as this issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78188255/how-to-import-properties-from-aws-secret-manager-in-spring-cloud-config-server